# Can user install virtual pdf (postscript) printer on Windows without admin rights?

Tags: pdf-generation, ghostscript, postscript, virtual-printer

Can user install virtual pdf (postscript) printer on Windows without admin rights?

By default (Ghostscript, doPDF...) require the admin right.

May be where is a some way to install virtual printer for user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds more like a Windows policy than anything else, which is set up by the administrator of the Windows installation.

The current shipping version of Ghostscript includes a signed .inf file, which avoids the problems previously encountered. However, the user must still have rights to add a printer, there's no way to add a printer without having the right to do so.